# Using Abstract and Interface Class - Building application in Salesforce

Tags: apex, design-patterns, oop

I have been intrigued by using design patterns, Object oriented concepts when programming. I do not have much hands on with using these concepts when programming salesforce. I do have a theoretical knowledge about them and learnt them using sample examples like - Car, Color , Hello world level. But I think the best way to learn how to use them is through hands on experience where I have requirements that would makes me think to use these concepts.

I heard from online forums that best way to learn about these concepts is reading through code used in an application and analyzing why they built it in such a way. Is there any resources that the community would recommend me to get a good grasp of how to use OOPs, design patterns , best practices when it comes to working on a project.

I do have a book references of where I can go to read about each concepts. but I am looking here for real world examples so that I get familiarized with them.

Comment: May not be the appropriate forum but it’s a question all of us wish we had the answer to at some point

Comment: Super recommend Force.com Enterprise Architecture by Andrew Fawcett, 2nd Edition for practical examples